# Should I use ReferenceProperty Prefetching or Duplicate the Referenced Entity's Column?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to understand how to use `ReferenceProperty` for common usage scenarios.
In a typical application, we always display Referenced Entity's columns.

For example, consider a Purchase Order application.

```py
class POCategory(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class POSubCategory(db.Model):
    category = db.ReferenceProperty(POCategory, collection_name='sub_categories')
    name = db.StringProperty()

class PurchaseOrder(db.Model):
    total_amount = db.FloatProperty()

class PurchaseOrderLineItem(db.Model):
    category = db.ReferenceProperty(POCategory, collection_name='po_line_items')
    sub_category = db.ReferenceProperty(POSubCategory, collection_name = 'po_line_items')
    amount = db.FloatProperty()
```

This is what we normally display in typical applications.

```
+---------------+---------------+--------+
|   Category    | Sub Category  | Amount |
+---------------+---------------+--------+
| Blue Category | Water         | $12.00 |
| Red Category  | Fire          | $20.00 |
+---------------+---------------+--------+
|          Purchase Order Total | $22.00 |
+---------------+---------------+--------+
```

Should I be using **ReferenceProperty Pre-fetching** for this to avoid N+1 select problem?
or
duplicate the category and sub-category names in my Purchase Order Line Item like below?

```py
class PurchaseOrderLineItem(db.Model):
    category = db.ReferenceProperty(POCategory, collection_name='po_line_items')
    category_name = db.StringProperty()

    sub_category = db.ReferenceProperty(POSubCategory, collection_name = 'po_line_items')
    sub_category_name = db.StringProperty()

    amount = db.FloatProperty()
```

Obviously, the names for categories and sub-categories are editable.
So when someone updates the `name` property, I will have to query and loop over all referenced `PurchaseOrderLineItem` entities and update my duplicate `name` properties.

```py
    #----------------------------------------
    #             BAD DESIGN
    #----------------------------------------
    po_category.name = 'New Category Name'

    # build list of line items to be updated
    update_list = []
    for child_line_item in po_category.po_line_items:
        child_line_item.category_name = po_entity.name
        update_list.append(child_line_item)

    db.put(po_category, update_list)
```

I know it is **NOT** a good scalable solution because over time we will have a lot of Line Items to be updated. RDBMS way of thinking is hard to get rid of.

So can anyone please teach me how to think for these kinds of typical scenarios?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, since you can often edit category name, you should not embed it into Line Item.

Instead use NDB (which automatically caches gets) and multi-get (one DB call to get multiple entities) to get categories and sub-categories.

Comment: Yeah NDB has better API design than DB, and I just have to do the ReferenceProperty prefetching technique to perform "SQL-JOIN-like" operations. No getting around it. Thank you for your answer.